# split by | and find unique values in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

i have a movie data from movielens dataset and i would like to select unique genre from the genres columns. this is the dataset

[image: movies dataset]

the result would look like this

[image: result]

can somebody help me to split and select unique genre from the genres columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
pd.unique(df["genres"].str.split("|", expand=True).stack())
```

**Output**:

```
array(['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Fantasy',
       'Horror','Action','Thriller'], dtype=object)
```

**Explanations**:

This part splits the genres of the column `genres` in one column per genre (the output is an extract):

```
df["genres"].str.split("|", expand=True)

    0           1           2       
0   Adventure   Animation   Children
1   Adventure   Children    Fantasy
2   Comedy      None        None
```

`.stack()` stacks all the columns into one:

```
df["genres"].str.split("|", expand=True).stack()

0    Adventure
1    Animation
2     Children
3       Comedy
4      Fantasy
```

Then, `pd.unique()` returns an array containing the uniques values of the Serie.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the 'genre' column of your dataset in to a list and then loop to add each individual genre to a wider list

```
genres = []
for mixed_genres in data.genres.to_list(): 
   genres.extend(mixed_genres.split("|"))
```

Then pull out only the unique values by using "set()"

```
unique_genres = list(set(genres))
```

And finally turn it back into a column so it looks exactly like your desired output.

```
pd.DataFrame(unique_genres,columns=["genres"])
```